# Getting 'str' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated' in Flask using Flask-Login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am trying to set up login for Flask using Flask-Login.  I have a CouchDB for users; the customer documents have an object called "user".

```
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__ (self, user) :
        self.name = user['name']
        self.password = user['password']
        self.id= user['id']

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)


def check_user(id):
    for row in db.query(map_auth):
        if row.value['id'] == id:
            authUser = User(row.value)
            return authUser
        else:
            return "User not found in database"

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return check_user(id)


@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for row in db.query(map_auth):
            if row.value['name'] == request.form['name'] and row.value['password'] == request.form['password']:
                authUser = User(row.value)
        flask_login.login_user(authUser)
        app.logger.debug(authUser.name)
        app.logger.debug(authUser.is_authenticated())
        app.logger.debug(authUser.is_active())
        return redirect(url_for('protected'))
    return render_template('login.html')
```

`map_auth` is a view function that from python-couchdb.  The view returns a list of JSONs with the following information for users: `{"name": "xxxx", "id":1, "password": "password"}`.

I verified that the `User` class works independently by simulating this in a Python shell.  When I use it in Flask, I get the following error.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_login.py", line 790, in decorated_view
    elif not current_user.is_authenticated:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'
```

I have already verified that the `authUser` object that I have used has `is_authenticated()` true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `user_loader` function (in your case the logic is in `check_user`) should return `None` if a userid is not valid. In your case a string `"User not found in database"` is returned, which creates the exception you are encountering.

Return `None` if the userid is not valid.

[Documenation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works):

> It should return `None` (**not raise an exception**) if the ID is not valid. (In that case, the ID will manually be removed from the session and processing will continue.)

Comment: Hi, Can you explain what the function of the user and request loader is?  I went through the documentation, but I did not fully understand it

Comment: You mean the User class and the `login_manager.user_loader`? Or what exactly do you mean with `request loader`?

Comment: yes.  I am currently using user_loader for authenticating my users.  As per my understanding, user_loader will check if the userid in the session actually exists in the database on every request.  I did'nt understand what the request_loader does in the documentation.

Comment: The User class represents user registered in your system. When a user is logged in the userID is saved in the cookie clientside. Now to know which user this is one needs to load the user from the database via this userid. This is what user_loader is. Sometimes you don't want to load a user by a cookie but by some other means (e.g. HTTP header information). request_loader is meant for that case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  But how does flask determine what the userID is?  Should i explicitly state it in the code (maybe with a session['userid'] = userid or something like that) or does it automatically get set?

Comment: flask-login does that for you already. From the documentation: `[Flask-login] will: Store the active user’s ID in the session, [...]`. You only need to provide the user_loader and then log user in via `login_user`.