# Flask login without database

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I need to implement a simple login functionality to one of the applications that I a working on using `flask-login`. The authentication checking is hardcoded if condition and it is validating whether username password equals to a string given. The code is like the following:

```
@auth_bp.route('/login', methods=["POST"])
def loginHandler():
    username = request.form.get('username')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    if username != 'admin' and password != 'Admin@123':
        flash('Please check your login details and try again.')
        return redirect(url_for('auth_bp.show_login'))

    login_user(username, False)
    # if the above check passes, then we know the user has the right credentials
    return redirect(url_for('migration_bp.list'))
```

and in `app.py` file, I have the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_manager
from auth.auth import auth_bp
from environments.environments import environments_bp
from migration.migration import migration_bp
from logs.logs import logs_bp

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads'

@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader():
    # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
    return 1

def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    login_manager_copy = LoginManager()
    login_manager_copy.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager_copy.init_app(app)

    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp, url_prefix='/auth')
    app.register_blueprint(environments_bp, url_prefix='/environments')
    app.register_blueprint(migration_bp, url_prefix='/migration')
    app.register_blueprint(logs_bp, url_prefix='/logs')

    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
    app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app().run(debug=True)
```

But this is showing an error as follows:

```
AttributeError: module 'flask_login.login_manager' has no attribute 'user_loader'
```

As I don't need database, I think the User modal given in the examples are not needed. But it is giving errors without it. How can I fix this ?

EDIT:

As per the suggestion below, I have added a User class as shown below:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin, LoginManager, login_manager


class User(UserMixin):

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return int(self.id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.powerlevel}')"
```

and added following code to `app.py` file:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

But it is still showing the same error.

Answer (score 2):

app.py you will have this:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, LoginManager, login_required, current_user, logout_user

app = Flask(__name__)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app) #defined above app=Flask(__name__)
login_manager.login_view = 'login' #logged out users will be redirected to this route if attempting to view a route that requires login

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
# This sets the callback for reloading a user from the session.
# The function you set should take a user ID and return a user object, or None if the user does not exist.
# id is str or int if the keys in data.USERS are str or int 
# "123123" or 123123 (see next section)
try:
    return data.USERS.get(str(id))
except:
    return None

@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
   if request.method == "POST":
       if request.form["login"]:
           id = request.form["id"]
           password = request.form["password"]
           response = data.confirmUserLogin(id, password)
           if response["status"] == True:
               # login the user
               # Login user, You should pass the actual user object to this. 
               # If the user’s is_active property is False, they will not be logged in unless force is True
               login_user(data.USERS[id])
               flash(response["message"])
               return redirect(url_for('index'))
           else:
               flash(response["message"])
               return redirect(url_for('login'))
    
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("login.html")
```

data.py:

```
#you can use: class User(Usermixin)
"""
UserMixin pre-defines these attributes for your User class:
def is_authenticated():
    ...
def is_active():
    ...
def is_anonymous():
    ...
def get_id():
    ...
"""
# or you can just define these attributes yourself
class User():
    def __init__(self, id, username, active=True):
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        self.active = active

    def is_active(self):
        # Here you should write whatever the code is
        # that checks the database if your user is active
        # return self.active
        # for demo i just return True
        return True 
    
    def is_authenticated(self):
        # for demo i just return True
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        # if you do not use Usermixin, this is important
        # user_loader load_user(id) uses this get_id attribute to load the id
        return self.id

# create local database of sample users
# Key are user id's : Value are User objects
USERS = {
    "123123": User("123123", "user1"),
    "456456": User("456456", "user2"),
    "789789": User("789789", "user3", False),
}

def confirmUserLogin(id, password):
    # check local db USERS for the id
    if USERS.get(sso):
        # get the user object (key's value)
        user = USERS.get(id)
        # check password
        if user.password == password:
            # entered password matches database password
            response = {"status":True, "message":"Login Successfull!"}
            return response
        else:
            # entered password DOES NOT match database password
            response = {"status":False, "message":"Wrong password, please try again."}
            return response
    else:
        # user does not exist
        response = {"status":False, "message":"User does not exist, please try again."}
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that Flask-Login will not work without a class representing the data storage, because at some point it needs to access the database to know if a user has logged in already and other auth requirements.

Clearly as it does not impose a storage restriction, I think you can cheat the system without a database.

First create the User class as specified in the docs, https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Define a class as so - all these methods are necessary.

```
class User:
    def is_authenticated():
        ...
    def is_active():
        ...
    def is_anonymous():
        ...
    def get_id():
        ...
```

Create a global variable that is of this user type and log users in and do whatever else. You do not necessarily need a database in which this class represents information in.

Let me know if you understood in the comments. Happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks Rohan for the answer. I have added a user class in a file called `models.py` and I have updated the code above. Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: That is a compulsary function that needs to be provided in your code. You need to use a decorator for this. I will link you to a similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603924/attributeerror-object-has-no-attribute-user-loader.

Comment: So the function needs to be there in the User class ? I have this function with decorator in `app.py` file and there only it showing the error.

Comment: I have added the unicode also, but still error is the same